# show swf files in cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp, flash

I'm New to CakePHP

I followed the steps that for the requirement in this page
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2008/11/25/flashhelper-a-wrapper-for-the-swfobject-js-class#page-2

and I having problem showing the swf files.

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: flash [APP/View/Themed/xxx/Layouts/site.ctp, line 120]

Fatal error: Call to a member function init() on a non-object in/home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/cakev1/app/View/Themed/xxx/Layouts/site.ctp on line 120
```

I had created a FlashHelper.php in /app/views/helpers folder and copied all the Component class provided in the page.

Javascript uploaded in /app/webroot/js folder.

And I don't understand what does it mean by "The helper added to your controller's helpers property".

Can anyone please explain it to me? Or point out what I did wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just copying the helper files doesn't make it load automagically. You need to tell your controller that you want to use the helper in your views, by putting this in the top part of your controller (just after the class definition is usually a good place):

```
public $helpers = array('Flash');
```

You can also add any additional helpers you want to use in there too. That way, it will load the helper and you can call it with `$this->Flash` from your views.

Comment: So the FlashHelper.php is in the correct position? I copy the Component Class provided and paste it in FlashHelper.php.
And do I need to create a new FlashController.php in Controller folder?